# Admin SDK - Reports API - Google Drive: does not return PREVIEW and PRINT events

Tags: google-admin-sdk

How can I get `PREVIEW` and `PRINT` events from Reports API?
Here are links to documentation:

1. `PREVIEW` -  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive#preview
2. `PRINT` - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive#print

Regarding `PREVIEW`, I've noticed that it creates just [VIEW](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive#view) even if I open the file in preview mode via Web app: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgr7U.png). So it's not clear when `PREVIEW` should be triggered.

Regarding `PRINT`, I used both ways:

- hotkey Command+P
- File -> Print
  Nothing work, it doesn't create `PRINT` event.

I'm using `googleapiclient` (Python) library to get activities. Here is a code:

```
client = build('admin', 'reports_v1', credentials=credentials)
response = client.activities().list(
    userKey='all', 
    applicationName='drive', 
    maxResults=5, 
    eventName='print',
).execute()
```

This code works properly for getting other events such as `DOWNLOAD`, `EDIT`, etc.
But for `PRINT` and `PREVIEW` it always returns the response without events:

```
{'kind': 'admin#reports#activities', 'etag': '"SOME_ETAG"'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an [already reported behaviour](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76336480) in [public issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker). I tried to perform your actions and I can confirm that I could reproduce your behaviour.

In order to bring more attention to this report please indicate that you are also affected by clicking on the star icon at the top left of this report.